# Do you restock hand cards at the end of each turn? Different language editions seem to have different rulings

Tags: edition-comparison, alhambra

Do you restock hand cards at the end of each turn, yes or no?

We've always played it so you restock your hand to four cards, as is explicitly stated in the Dutch rules. Other languages aren't as specific.

The English rules for Alhambra, by Queen, describe the actions at the end of a turn as follows:

> **[English](http://www.world-of-board-games.com.sg/docs/Alhambra.pdf)**
>   When your turn is over it is the next player's turn. Before the next player decides what to do, any money cards or building tiles which have been removed are replaced with new ones **so that there are four of each again**.

Now, if I look at the Dutch rules (also by Queen) and translate them, there's a significant difference.

> **[Dutch](http://www.jumbo.eu/media/products/assets/manuals/1cfe9ec7-00cd-51c3-8aa9-21251c407b57.pdf)**
>   When your turn is over it is the next player's turn. Now all money cards and missing building tiles are supplemented **until every player once again has 4 cards**.

Normally I would look to the German rules (also by Queen) for an answer, since the game is made in Germany. This one reads:

> **[German](http://www.spielezentrum.de/Turniere/DM2007/Download07/RV07-Downl/Alhambra-Regl.pdf)**
>   After you end your turn, the next player is up. For that, missing money cards and missing building tiles are **restocked to four each**.

Comment: The [French rules](http://www.ludosbxl.irisnet.be/docnotice/1000_2009_09_1_14_42_54.pdf) say "It is then the next player's turn. Beforehand, you must fill the money cards and the building tiles necessary to each reach four."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't restock your hand of cards, you restock the four money cards on the board which are available to take, the same way you restock the tiles available to buy. That looks consistent with the English and German rules; I would assume the Dutch is the mistake, that they meant until each *supply* has four cards/tiles.

I would say the English and German rules are fairly specific about that, and it takes some substantial stretching to get them to mean anything else. And the Dutch sounds like fairly awkward phrasing for restocking the supply on the table, which surely must be done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything else in the rules is the same as the English translation (i.e. you adding cards to your hand ends your turn), it would make no sense to also "restock your hand to four cards from the supply". So, in agreement with others, I think the Dutch must have a mistranslation.